# How do pilots hold the runway centerline during takeoff?

Tags: airliner, commercial-aviation, takeoff, taxiing

Holding the taxiway centerline during taxi is usually done with the nose gear tiller in commercial aircraft. During take-off, until which speed is the tiller used before using pedals to control runway centerline alignment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once you've lined up nicely on the runway, you only need the rudder pedals as they do provide *enough* nose gear steering for the takeoff roll even at low speed.

> Rudder pedal steering is available during takeoff, landing, and taxiing when small directional changes are required. Full deflection of the rudder pedals produces about 7 degrees of nose wheel steering ([airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=740037)).

The 7 degrees figure quoted above will vary by plane.

Tiller is used when tight turns are needed. Remember most airliners don't have a tiller on the first officer's side, yet they do takeoff without the captain steering for them.

[image]
([YouTube](https://youtu.be/2cq3JgW7HFg?t=74))

In the linked video we see the captain let go of the tiller as soon as he is lined up on the runway. Also notice the tiller move on its own afterward, which indicates that the rudder pedal [nose wheel] steering is being used.

Comment: Just a historical note to say that a minority of 747-100/200 aircraft did not have a link between the rudder pedals and the nose gear. In those aircraft it was necessary to use the tiller to track the runway centerline until you had sufficient airspeed for the rudder to handle that. And, since both the captain and the first officer had tillers, a takeoff by the first officer did not mean the captain had to run the tiller.